# Bug with association message

Tags: bug, status-completed, linked-accounts

After logging in for the first time at Superuser.com, I went back to StackOverflow and received the following message:

"You've associated your Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow accounts: +100 reputation"

Anyone has had the same problem?

Comment: I wish I had this problem more often.

Comment: You mean the message should be `Stack Overflow and Super User accounts`?

Comment: How is this "bydesign"?

Comment: The bug is the nonsensical message, not the amount reputation given.  Seems like this probably isn't "bydesign"

Comment: Months later: @S.Mark, yes, I'm talking about the message, not the bonus itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a minor issue when the "wrong" site was displayed here -- which I corrected. But, the +100 can be awarded on all sites -- one time *only* per site.

---

This issue was re-introduced (technically, an entirely different cause; but the same manifested symptoms).  It will be fixed with the next deploy.

Comment: given the recent duplicate, I guess it's not fixed completely: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51058/youve-associated-your-stack-overflow-and-stack-overflow-accounts-closed

Comment: Yes I just got this about 2 minutes ago which lead me to this question.

Comment: I got +100 rep on SO just now because of this... because I had >200 rep on SO? Is it a reward for hitting 200 rep, to get a free 100 rep boost?

Comment: I am experiencing the same bug after associating Server Fault and SO accounts. To clarify, I do get the points (that's fine), but the message says "Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow".

Comment: Confirmed this bug just now :)

Comment: still not corrected, just got it.

Comment: @jcom totally different issue

Comment: I've seen the "totally different issue" right now when signing up to Android for the first time.

Comment: And btw I didn't get +100 on Android which is kind of inconvenient - I can't vote, can' comment, can't anything.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug it's a feature! No really!

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/new-automatic-account-association/

In the comments, specifically:

> as long as at least one of the accounts in the “pair” being associated has > 200 rep, **the +100 bonus will apply on both sites (but only once per site in total)** -- Jeff Atwood

Answer (score 1):

I just got that bug today. I just made a serverfault account (I thought I had one but could'nt find it) I'd post an image but I'm too n00b to be allowed that..

"You've associated your Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow accounts: +100 reputation"

and I didn't get the +100 on ServerFault either! (or this one!)

Comment: and now the question I asked on ServerFault yesterday just disappeared!  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Is this supposed to be fixed? I just saw this message:

> You've associated your Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow accounts: +100 reputation