# You've associated your Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow accounts

Tags: bug, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bug with association message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50554/bug-with-association-message)

Small glitch after linking my SO account with meta SO account, this was shown on top of SO:

> You've associated your Stack Overflow
>   and Stack Overflow accounts: +100
>   reputation

I was secretly hoping my rep points would overflow, alas it appears to just be a typo.

Comment: Agreed. Note that the typo *didn't* occur on Meta SO, that showed the expected result, the typo was only on SO.