# Why doesn't my question show up?

Tags: support, questions, search

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953611/variadic-constructors) is invisible in the [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) section, but visible in the [C++0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x) section. What gives?

Comment: I edited out the latter of your questions because it's already been dealt with [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50554/bug-with-association-message). Also, please ask one question per issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I see it at #3 in the list when the "newest" tab is selected.

## Are you looking at a different tab?

[image]

Also have you forced a refresh - the page could well be cached. There will be more questions tagged "c++" than "c++0x" so it's more likely that the "c++" page is cached for longer.

Comment: LOL, I never noticed there were different tabs. Now i feel stupid :)

Comment: I was just caught by the same mistake! =P Added an image to this answer.